# I'm working at editing one web page with C# and .Net platform. I have a logout button that when I click it shows me an error

Tags: c#, .net, session, logout

An exception of type '`System.NullReferenceException`' occurred in `App_Code.p9yip9ku.dll` but was not handled in user code

`Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` this is the error.

My code is:

```
using System.Configuration;
using UserActionLogger;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for UserActions
/// </summary>
public static class UserData
{
    private static UserActions _uaUserActions;

    public static void InitUserData(int uID, string IP)
    {
        var cString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["basteConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        _uaUserActions = new UserActions(cString, uID, IP);
    }

    public static void Logout()
    {
        _uaUserActions.Logout();
    }

    public static void InsertAction(int actionid, long value)
    {
        _uaUserActions.InsertAction(actionid, value);
    }

}
```

and the function is called like :

```
 else if (type == 1002) //User Logout
            {
                Session["current_user"] = "NoUser";

                UserData.Logout();
                var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                this.Response.Write(jss.Serialize(Session["current_user"]));
                this.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                this.Response.End();
                //TODO : LOGOUT
            }
```

Comment: Check if its getting call InitUserData(). I think _uaUserActions is null

Comment: in which line you get exception?  maybe `ConnectionStrng` is null

Comment: @esiprogrammer here: _uaUserActions.Logout();

Comment: you have to call `InitUserData` before calling `UserData.Logout();` because `_uaUserActions` is null at that point

Comment: Thank you @esiprogrammer i resolved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i resolved:

```
 else if (type == 1002) //User Logout
            {
                UserDTO user = (UserDTO)Session["current_user"];
                int id = user.ID;
                string IPja = this.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                UserData.InitUserData(id, IPja);
                Session["current_user"] = "NoUser";

                UserData.Logout();
                var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                this.Response.Write(jss.Serialize(Session["current_user"]));
                this.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                this.Response.End();
                //TODO : LOGOUT
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In ur `UserData` has `_uaUserActions` which is null when you call `UserData.logout` you have to call `UserData.InitUserData(uID, IP);` before `UserData.Logout();`

```
else if (type == 1002) //User Logout
        {
            Session["current_user"] = "NoUser";

            UserData.InitUserData(uID,IP); //you have to call this befor Logout method.
            UserData.Logout();
            var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            this.Response.Write(jss.Serialize(Session["current_user"]));
            this.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            this.Response.End();
            //TODO : LOGOUT
        }
```